# Python / Pandas: Looping through a list of numbers

Tags: python, excel, list, loops, pandas

I am trying to create a loop involving Pandas/ Python and an Excel file. The column in question is named "ITERATION" and it has numbers ranging from 1 to 6. I'm trying to query the number of hits in the Excel file in the following iteration ranges:

- 1 to 2
- 3
- 4 to 6

I've already made a preset data frame named "df".

```
iteration_list = ["1,2", "3", "4,5,6"]
i = 1
for k in iteration_list:
    table = df.query('STATUS == ["Sold", "Refunded"]')
    table["ITERATION"] = table["ITERATION"].apply(str)
    table = table.query('ITERATION == ["%s"]' % k)
    table = pd.pivot_table(table, columns=["Month"], values=["ID"], aggfunc=len)
    table.to_excel(writer, startrow = i)
    i = i + 3
```

The snippet above works only for the number "3". The other 2 scenarios don't seem to work as it literally searches for the string "1,2". I've tried other ways such as:

- iteration_list = [1:2, 3, 4:6]
- iteration_list = [{1:2}, 3, {4:6}]
  to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

***EDIT***

After looking over Stidgeon's answer, I seemed to come up with the following alternatives. Stidgeon's answer DOES provide an output but not the one I'm looking for (it gives 6 outputs - from iteration 1 to 6 in each loop).

Above, my list was the following:

```
iteration_list = ["1,2", "3", "4,5,6"]
```

If you play around with the quotation marks, you could input exactly what you want. Since your strings is literally going to be inputted into this line where %s is:

```
table = table.query('ITERATION == ["%s"]' % k)
```

You can essentially play around with the list to fit your precise needs with quotations. Here is a solution that could work:

```
list = ['1", "2', 3, '4", "5", "6']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just focusing on getting the values out of the list of strings, this works for me (though - as always - there may be more Pythonic approaches):

```
lst = ['1,2','3','4,5,6']

for item in lst:
    items = item.split(',')
    for _ in items:
        print int(_)
```

Though instead of printing at the end, you can pass the value to your script.

This will work if all your strings are either single numbers or numbers separated by commas. If the data are consistently formatted like that, you may have to tweak this code.